# Checkbox change event does not fire upon using dispatchEvent in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, dom-events

I have a `Checkbox` component with an `onChange` event handler. I want to trigger the `onChange` event in another elements `click` handler. I am creating a custom event and dispatch the event in the click handler. I could see this works fine in a native way whereas I could not achieve the same in react.

### Use of Checkbox component

```
<Checkbox onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

I have created an example, please find the URL https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dvrssp?file=Checkbox.js

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things. You are not using the correct prop in your CheckBox component. You are accessing `this.props.onChange`  , it should be `this.props.onCLick` instead.

Also you need to make a `call` to the function on the radio button `onChange`.

I have edited the code. You can check it here. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mwqfxv?file=Checkbox.js

Comment: Thanks for your response. yes there was a mistake in my code. i have corrected and updated the url. I have an `onClick` event attached to the `span` and `onChange` event is passed to the `Checkbox` component. Upon clicking on the label which is the text inside the `span`, the checkbox should be checked and unchecked. i can do that by using `label` tag with `for` attribute but i can not use them due to some restriction. Please find the updated url https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dvrssp?file=Checkbox.js